# Combining Lists in a specified sequence

Tags: list-manipulation

I have 3 lists called as List6, List7 and List8 which are as:

```
List6 = Table[{x1[[i, j]]}, {i, 101}, {j, 101}];
List7 = Table[{y1[[i, j]]}, {i, 101}, {j, 101}];
List8 = Table[{xDisp1[[i, j]]}, {i, 101}, {j, 101}];
```

I want to combine them  and use a code below

```
data = MapThread[{#1[[1]], #2[[1]], #3[[1]]} &, {List6, List7, 
List8}];
```

to achieve a list which will have terms such that

```
{{x1[[1,1]],y1[[1,1]],xDisp1[[1,1]]},{x1[[1,2]],y1[[1,2]],xDisp[[1,2]]},...,
 {x1[[101,101]],y1[[101,101]],xDisp[[101,101]]}}
```

but I cannot achieve with that code. Where do I make a mistake and how is it possible to correct the code, please ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

You may use `Transpose`.

As you have not provided the definitions for `x1`, `y1`, and `xDisp1` I will use indices in the values place. I will also use a shorter series for the demonstration.

With

```
list6 = Table[{x1[i, j]}, {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
list7 = Table[{y1[i, j]}, {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
list8 = Table[{xDisp1[i, j]}, {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
```

Then

```
Flatten[Transpose[{list6, list7, list8}, {4, 2, 3, 1}], 2]
```

> ```
> {{x1[1, 1], y1[1, 1], xDisp1[1, 1]}, {x1[1, 2], y1[1, 2], xDisp1[1, 2]}, 
>  {x1[2, 1], y1[2, 1], xDisp1[2, 1]}, {x1[2, 2], y1[2, 2], xDisp1[2, 2]}}
> ```

Key to understanding the above is to examine the `Dimensions` of the list you want to `Transpose`.

```
Dimensions@{list6, list7, list8}
```

> ```
> {3, 2, 2, 1}
> ```

Next notice that you want the 4th-dim (the individual entries), then the 2nd-
 and 3rd-dim (the row and columns), and finally 1st-dim (the items from each set).  `Flatten` is used to reduce dimensions of the result by flattening out 2 dimensions (row and column).

Note that starting in version 11.2 you have an shorthand method with `TwoWayRule` since you are doing one level swap.

```
Flatten[Transpose[{List6, List7, List8}, 1 <-> 4], 2]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is just to [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) your lists first, and then use [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html). Following @Edmund's use of indices rather than lists for `x1`, `y1` and `xDisp`, take

```
List6 = Table[{x1[i, j]}, {i, 101}, {j, 101}];
List7 = Table[{y1[i, j]}, {i, 101}, {j, 101}];
List8 = Table[{xDisp1[i, j]}, {i, 101}, {j, 101}];
```

Then

```
data = Transpose[Flatten /@ {List6, List7, List8}];
```

gives you your output. The dimensions of `data` and its first and last three entries are:

```
Dimensions[data]
data[[1 ;; 3]]
data[[-3 ;; -1]]

(* {10201, 3}

   {{x1[1, 1], y1[1, 1], xDisp1[1, 1]}, {x1[1, 2], y1[1, 2], xDisp1[1, 2]}, 
    {x1[1, 3], y1[1, 3], xDisp1[1, 3]}}

   {{x1[101, 99], y1[101, 99], xDisp1[101, 99]}, {x1[101, 100], y1[101, 100], xDisp1[101, 100]}, 
    {x1[101, 101], y1[101, 101], xDisp1[101, 101]}} *)
```